# How to concatenate the lower column index and sole row index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

The following code produces a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import tabula

page_number = "1"
pdf_url = "https://usviber.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/A23-OCT.pdf"

# Reads the PDF

tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_url, pages=page_number)

df = tables[1]

# Selects relvant columns and rows

numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=["number"])
df = df.drop(numeric_columns.columns[(numeric_columns < 0).any()], axis=1)
df = df.loc[2:13, :].iloc[:, :5]

# Set the column index to the island names

df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)

# Rename columns based on year

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["St Thomas", "St. Croix"], ["2022", "2023"]], names=["Island", "Year"]
)

# Map the index to uppercase and extract the first 3 characters

df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: str(x).upper()[:3])
df.index.set_names("Month", inplace=True)
```

Here is the dataframe it makes

```
print(df)
Island St Thomas         St. Croix        
Year        2022    2023      2022    2023
Month                                     
JAN       55,086  60,470    11,550  12,755
FEB       57,929  56,826    12,441  13,289
MAR       72,103  64,249    14,094  15,880
APR       67,469  56,321    12,196  13,092
MAY       60,092  49,534    13,385  16,497
JUN       67,026  56,950    14,009  15,728
JUL       66,353  61,110    13,768  16,879
AUG       50,660  42,745    10,673  12,102
SEP       24,507  25,047     6,826   6,298
OCT       34,025  34,462    10,351   9,398
NOV       44,500     NaN     9,635     NaN
DEC       58,735     NaN    12,661     NaN
```

What I want, is to have the island names be the row indices, and the concatenation of the month and year to be the column names, resulting in a 2 row 24 column dataset. So, row one would be St. Thomas. The first column would be JAN2022, and the value of interest would be 56086. The next would be FEB2022, and the value 57929, and so on until December of 2023. The second row would be St. Croix, with the corresponding values and time periods as above. How might I do this?

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Isolate the question and provide the input and desired output as a text table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) ([`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)), then flatten the MultiIndex columns with [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
out = df.stack().T

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')

# or
# out.columns = map(''.join, out.columns)
```

Output:

```
          JAN2022 JAN2023 FEB2022 FEB2023 MAR2022 MAR2023 APR2022 APR2023 MAY2022 MAY2023 JUN2022 JUN2023 JUL2022 JUL2023 AUG2022 AUG2023 SEP2022 SEP2023 OCT2022 OCT2023 NOV2022 DEC2022
Island                                                                                                                                                                                   
St Thomas  55,086  60,470  57,929  56,826  72,103  64,249  67,469  56,321  60,092  49,534  67,026  56,950  66,353  61,110  50,660  42,745  24,507  25,047  34,025  34,462  44,500  58,735
St. Croix  11,550  12,755  12,441  13,289  14,094  15,880  12,196  13,092  13,385  16,497  14,009  15,728  13,768  16,879  10,673  12,102   6,826   6,298  10,351   9,398   9,635  12,661
```